# Bluetooth headset recognized by BT 4 dongle, but no music heard

Tags: sound, bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker, audio-player

I just installed Kubuntu 18.04 and updated it. Next I plugged in an [Asus BT400 dongle](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/USBBT400/specifications/) and connected to my BT earbuds. My earbuds were successfully connected and appear in the list of output audio devices. Performing a simple test of raising and lowering the volume of these earbuds (using KDE sound mixer) demonstrates that they're working - I can hear short "pops" indicating the volume is being changed. All good up til this point.

Unfortunately, sounds played on the computer (eg, Chrome browser and VLC media player) play on a wired speaker (line-out), but do not play on the BT earbuds.

I've tried: restarting the workstation; re-installing the adapter and devices; testing with a different brand/type of earphones (same result).

It must be something simple as I see the device in sound mixer and can even hear the volume when changing it... so why doesn't the sound being played on the line-out speaker play on either of the BT headsets?

Output of `dmesg | grep Blue`:

[image: output of dmesg | grep Blue BEFORE]

EDIT: After seeing the output of dmesg (thanks K7AAY), I downloaded and installed the missing file. The output of dmesg is now different, but the trouble I'm experiencing remains (no change).

Output of the same command after:

[image: output of dmesg AFTER]

Status of Bluetooth service:

[image: output of service bluetooth status]

Comment: solved! I changed the default playback device from BT-earbuds to Line-in, then changed it back to BT-earbuds, and they started working, rebooted/tested/done

Comment: Make it an answer and click on the check mark to show it really, truly, solved it for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, that was not a lasting solution. After several minutes of listening, the BT earbuds stop working. To "fix" it, I change default device in KDE sound mixer to speaker. Then change the default back to BT earbuds. That solves it temporarily. Then I'm stuck in that loop. (also they sound very tinny compared to my phone, or another workstation, but that's probably a separate issue)

Comment: I'm going to try a different version of Ubuntu, or if necessary, a different distro. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: fyi, I replaced KUbuntu-18.04 with KUbuntu-19.10 and the earbuds work fine with Kubuntu-19.10